# Calculating Covariance Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, covariance

I am implementing a PCA algorithm in MATLAB. I see two different approaches to calculating the covariance matrix:

```
C = sampleMat.' * sampleMat ./ nSamples;
```

and

```
C = cov(data);
```

What is the difference between these two methods?

**PS 1:** When I use `cov(data)` is that unnecessary:

```
meanSample = mean(data,1);
data = data - repmat(data, nSamples, 1);
```

**PS 2:**

At first approach should I use `nSamples` or `nSamples - 1`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short: `cov` mainly just adds convenience to the bare formula.

If you type

```
edit cov
```

You'll see a lot of stuff, with these lines all the way at the bottom:

```
xc = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m);  % Remove mean    
if flag
    xy = (xc' * xc) / m;
else
    xy = (xc' * xc) / (m-1);  % DEFAULT 
end
```

which is essentially the same as your first line, save for the subtraction of the column-means.

Read [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance) on sample covariances to see why there is a minus-one in the default path.

Note however that your first line uses normal transpose (`.'`), whereas the `cov`-version uses conjugate-transpose (`'`). This will make the output of `cov` different in the context of complex-valued data.

Also note that `cov` is a function call to a non-built in function. That means that there will be a (possibly severe) performance penalty when using `cov` in a loop; Matlab's JIT compiler cannot accelerate non-built in functions.

Comment: With the caveat that complex numbers are handled differently from the code in the question.

Comment: According to your edit 2, does it better to use first line? and which one is the correct one or are they same to use conjugate-transpose and transpose to calculate covariance?

Comment: @kamaci: it depends. If you need to calculate only 1 covariance matrix per run, it's just easier to use `cov`. If you need to do it hundreds of times in a loop, with different data sets, etc., using the bare formula will be much faster and is overall the better trade-off. As mentioned above: the output of `cov` will only be different from your first attempt, if your `data` is complex-valued. If it only contains real values, the outputs will be identical.

Comment: I will run it only once however my data is too big, so still using cov is OK?

Comment: @kamaci: what do you mean, "too big"? How big is that?

Comment: I will use my implementation on big data so every line performance is important for me

Comment: @kamaci: Just profile: `tic; cov(data); toc` versus `tic; sampleMat.' * sampleMat ./ nSamples; toc`. I suspect the difference will be marginal for just 1 run.

Comment: Thanks for everything, I have tested performance and first one is better. I have real values but covariance matrices have different values?

Comment: @kamaci: perhaps your data goes through the stuff in the `else` clause?

Comment: @kamaci: Also, the `cov` subtracts the mean prior to calculation. Have you done this also in `sampleMat`? If not, then the outcomes will be different of course...

Comment: I just use cov(data), how can that flag change?

Comment: It seems that you got the point. Can you check my question again?

Comment: @kamaci: The flag is `false` by default; see [the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Calculating_the_sample_covariance) to see why.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis for last time can you check my question?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20570/discussion-between-kamaci-and-rody-oldenhuis)